What to do with duct in attic if I want to put in floor boards
We have big duct pipes running through the attic. We want to put flooring down but the ducts are long and thick and I don’t know if we can move than

first, determine if you can actually install a floor

...and add pics of the attic and ducts in question.

This begs the question, flooring for what?  With ducts there,  you cannot make it living space without moving them.  If for storage there is still the question of can the structure support the weight.  So is the question,  Can I move ducts in my attic?  The answer is yes, but it could be extremely complicated...or not depending on what you have and where is is.  All that information is not provided in your question. Please give more details with pictures for more help.

Sorry. First timer here. Trying to put flooring down in the attic for storage or extra space or whatever. I think we have a flex duct. What can I do to get it off the floor for more space? My son says to just strap it to the ceiling but I don’t want to break it. My husband… nevermind he’s no help .  So we have an attic. We want to do something, anything with it. Start with subfloor then floor. Get that stupid duct out of the way. If we can’t do anything with it how can we build around it?

You will get much more useful comments and maybe answers if you provide pics of the space where you want to put flooring.
